# A:active on empty link not working

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a table with link buttons that doesnt load new page but they just use onclick event to hide/display another tables. However I need to highlight the button which one is active but it doesnt work/ When you click and hold the mouse the button is highlighted but when you drop the mouse it fade again.

```
<div class="category2"><a href="#" onclick="showStuff('tabulka-adidas'); return false;">Adidas</a></div>
<div class="category2"><a href="#" onclick="showStuff('tabulka-nike'); return false;" >Nike</a></div>
<div class="category2"><a href="#" onclick="showStuff('tabulka-everlast'); return false;">Everlast</a></div>
```

see fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/LnqbU/11/

How can I highlight currently active button ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you want this to work with CSS only? Because if you want to have the selected button to stay solid red, you might want to use some JS to add a class which can be the same as the `:active` pseudo class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a:active` is the style triggered when the link is clicked (when you hold down the mousebutton).

What you want, you'll need Javascript or jQuery to add a "active" class to the link.
For example with jQuery:

HTML:

```
<div class="category2"><a class="linkButton" href="#" onclick="showStuff('tabulka-adidas'); return false;">Adidas</a></div>
<div class="category2"><a class="linkButton" href="#" onclick="showStuff('tabulka-nike'); return false;" >Nike</a></div>
<div class="category2"><a class="linkButton" href="#" onclick="showStuff('tabulka-everlast'); return false;">Everlast</a></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".linkButton").on("click", function() {
    $(".linkButton").removeClass( "active" );
    $(this).addClass( "active" );
});
```

I updated your fiddle with the above code ([**check here**](http://jsfiddle.net/LnqbU/12/)), which also triggers the parents CSS. :)

Comment: Hello thanks this works for me however I have to click twice on  button. First click: Button is highlited, second click: Removed highlited style, third click : Style applied again. I want to make it one one click

Answer (score 2):

> When you click and hold the mouse the button is highlighted but when you drop the mouse it fade again.

That’s because that is how `:active` is [defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes):

> *“The :active pseudo-class applies while an element is being activated by the user. For example, between the times the user presses the mouse button and releases it.”*

---

> How can I highlight currently active button ?

Since you are using JavaScripot already, why not give it a class when it’s “active” and format it via that?

(And of course then remove the class from the previously activated element when a new one gets activated.)